# How to create a minimal standalone WEB application with Django

Tags: django, pyramid

Using Pyramid framework a minimal standalone (i.e. not using external WEB server) WEB application can be created as follows:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response

def hello_world(request):
    return Response('Hello World!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Configurator() as config:
        config.add_route('hello', '/')
        config.add_view(hello_world, route_name='hello')
        app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 1234, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

How to achieve this with Django framework?

Comment: Django is not meant to be a minimal application framework; with some finagling, you can technically achieve a single-file Django project that is run via e.g. `wsgiref.simple_server`, but it's not meant for that. In other words: why are you asking?

Comment: I just don't want to add another framework and use Django.

Comment: Well, see my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

As my comment says, Django is not meant for this. However, in the interest of curiosity, this is approximately the smallest two-route Django app-project-amalgam I can think of:

```
import os

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import path

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", __name__)
ROOT_URLCONF = __name__
urlpatterns = [
    path("honk", lambda request: HttpResponse("Honk!")),
    path("", lambda request: HttpResponse("Hello World!")),
]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

    server = make_server("", 8000, get_wsgi_application())
    server.serve_forever()
```

You can paste that into a file and run it with e.g. `python minimal_django.py`, then navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000/honk. (There is no database, no static file serving, no auto-reload, nothing. Just a hello and a honk.)

But again, **Django is not meant for this sort of stuff! Don't do this at home!**

Comment: Of course, Django framework is all about creating complicated web apps, but I'm curious, what are drawbacks of using it in such way for really small apps?

Comment: Django is not designed for single file/small app development. It assumes certain features exist and are used, like its own peculiar settings file format, admin user interface and so on. By default most of these features are on. Most of the features are also built into the Django core package, like its ORM. It's the opposite for Pyramid and Flask  where you enable the features and install them as plugins one by one.